# Por que no me toma el array

Tags: javascript, json, promesas

`

```js
const API_URL = './productos.json' 



async function obtenerInfoProductos(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch (API_URL)
        const data = await response.json()

            if (data.length > 0){
                productos.push(...data)
                cargarProductos(productos)
                    onClickBtn()
            }

    } catch (error) {
        toast("no hay productos disponibles","red")
    }
}
    

const contenedorProductos = document.querySelector("#contenedor-productos");
const botonesCategorias = document.querySelectorAll(".boton-categoria");
const tituloPrincipal = document.querySelector("#titulo-principal");
let botonesAgregar = document.querySelectorAll(".producto-agregar");
const numerito = document.querySelector("#numerito");


function cargarProductos(productosElegidos) {

    contenedorProductos.innerHTML = "";

    productosElegidos.forEach(producto => {

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("producto");
        div.innerHTML =  ` 
        <div class="carta card m-5 p-5 border-warning">
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" class="producto-imagen card-img-top" alt="${producto.titulo}">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="producto-titulo card-title">${producto.titulo}</h5>
        <div class="producto-precio card-footer-precio">
            <big class="producto-precio text">$${producto.precio}</big>
          </div>
          <a class="producto-agregar btn btn-dark" id="${producto.id}" role="button">Agregar al carrito</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        `;
        contenedorProductos.append(div);
    })

    actualizarBotonesAgregar();
}

cargarProductos(productos);

botonesCategorias.forEach(boton => {
    boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        botonesCategorias.forEach(boton => boton.classList.remove("active"));
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

        if (e.currentTarget.id != "todos") {
            const productoCategoria = productos.find(producto => producto.categoria.id === e.currentTarget.id);
            tituloPrincipal.innerText = productoCategoria.categoria.nombre;
            const productosBoton = productos.filter(producto => producto.categoria.id === e.currentTarget.id);
            cargarProductos(productosBoton);
        } else {
            tituloPrincipal.innerText = "Todos los productos";
            cargarProductos(productos);
        }

    })
});

function actualizarBotonesAgregar() {
    botonesAgregar = document.querySelectorAll(".producto-agregar");

    botonesAgregar.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener("click", agregarAlCarrito);
    });
}

let productosEnCarrito;

let productosEnCarritoLS = localStorage.getItem("productos-en-carrito");

if (productosEnCarritoLS) {
    productosEnCarrito = JSON.parse(productosEnCarritoLS);
    actualizarNumerito();
} else {
    productosEnCarrito = [];
}

function agregarAlCarrito(e) {
    const idBoton = e.currentTarget.id;
    const productoAgregado = productos.find(producto => producto.id === idBoton);

    if(productosEnCarrito.some(producto => producto.id === idBoton)) {
        const index = productosEnCarrito.findIndex(producto => producto.id === idBoton);
        productosEnCarrito[index].cantidad++;
    } else {
        productoAgregado.cantidad = 1;
        productosEnCarrito.push(productoAgregado);
    }

    actualizarNumerito();

    localStorage.setItem("productos-en-carrito", JSON.stringify(productosEnCarrito));
}

function actualizarNumerito() {
    let nuevoNumerito = productosEnCarrito.reduce((acc, producto) => acc + producto.cantidad, 0);
    numerito.innerText = nuevoNumerito;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  background: var(--color-light);
  background-image: linear-gradient(105deg, rgba(241, 245, 209, 0.4), #fcfaf7), url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1310847/pexels-photo-1310847.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; }

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  grid-template-columns: 80px auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 15%; }

footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: #f0d01c;
  margin-top: auto;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px; }

.container__footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px; }

.box__footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px; }
  .box__footer .terms {
    max-width: 350px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: auto;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .box__footer h4 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: auto;
    font-weight: bold; }
  .box__footer a {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: auto;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .box__footer a:hover {
      opacity: 0.8; }
    .box__footer a .fab {
      font-size: 20px; }

.box__carrito {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 40px; }
  .box__carrito p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: auto; }
      
.box__copyright {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 40px; }
  .box__copyright p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: auto; }

.menu__index {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px; }
  .menu__index li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center; }
    .menu__index li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: grey;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      color: whitesmoke; }

.conteiner__index1 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  z-index: 1; }
  .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index {
    width: 330px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.25s; }
    .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index:hover {
      transform: translateY(-15px);
      box-shadow: 0 12px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
    .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index img {
      width: 330px;
      height: 220px; }
    .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index h4 {
      font-weight: 600; }
    .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index p {
      padding: 0 1rem;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300; }
    .conteiner__index1 .Honey__index a {
      font-weight: 500;
      text-decoration: none; }

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  body {
    padding: 0 0em; } }

.catalogo {
  top: 0; }

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .tarjeta {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; } }

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .tarjeta > .card:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0; } }

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .tarjeta > .card {
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0; } }

.tarjeta > .card {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem; }

.tarjeta > .card {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem; }

.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.75s; }

.division {
  height: 50px; }

.iindex {
  top: -48px; }

.movs {
  margin-right: 5px; }

#border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow black;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 7px; }

.display-1 {
  text-align: center; }

.tracking-in-expand {
  -webkit-animation: tracking-in-expand 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) both;
  animation: tracking-in-expand 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) both; }

@-webkit-keyframes tracking-in-expand {
  0% {
    letter-spacing: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0; }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.6; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes tracking-in-expand {
  0% {
    letter-spacing: -0.5em;
    opacity: 0; }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.6; }
  100% {
    opacity: 1; } }


.carta{
  height: 500px;
  width: 220px;
}

@media (min-width: 425px) {
  .carta {
    height:500px; 
    width: 300px;; } }

@media(min-width: 425px){
.producto-imagen{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}  } 


.card-footer-precio {
  background-color: #f0d01c;
  text-align: center;
   }

@media  (min-width: 425px){   
.producto-agregar{
  height: 38.8px;
  width: 170px;
}  } 

.contenedor-carrito {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.carrito-productos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.carrito-producto {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.carrito-producto-imagen {
  width: 4rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.carrito-producto small {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.carrito-producto-eliminar {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carrito-acciones {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.carrito-acciones-vaciar {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carrito-acciones-derecha {
  display: flex;
}

.carrito-acciones-total {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;

}

.carrito-acciones-comprar {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.carro{
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
}

@media(min-width: 425px){
.carro{
  height: 50px;
  width: 160px;
}}

.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d492dc1c0b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/diseno.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Honey Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="./img/icono/icono.ico" alt="logo">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar catalogo navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color: #F7D30B;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
          <img src="../img/icono/logo.png" alt="logo" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
          Honey Store
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../index.html">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./contactenos.html">Contactenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Nuestros Productos
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a id="todos" class="boton-menu boton-categoria dropdown-item">Todos nuestros productos</a></li>
              <li><a id="nintendo" class="boton-menu boton-categoria dropdown-item" >Nintendo</a></li>
              <li><a id="playstation" class="boton-menu boton-categoria dropdown-item" >Playstation</a></li>
              <li><a id="xbox" class="boton-menu boton-categoria dropdown-item" >Xbox</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" class="boton-menu boton-carrito" href="./carrito.html">
              <i class="bi bi-cart-fill"></i> Carrito <span id="numerito" class="numerito">0</span>
          </a>
          </li>
          </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="EN ARGENTINA NACI" aria-label="Buscar">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="division"></div>
  <h1 class="titulo-principal tracking-in-expand display-1 mt-5" id="titulo-principal">Todos los productos</h1>
      <div id="contenedor-productos" class="contenedor-productos conteiner__index1">
      </div>
  </main>
</div>
    <footer>
      <div class="container__footer">
        <div class="box__footer">
        <div class="terms"
        <p><b>Jugamos por muchos motivos: para dar rienda suelta a la imaginación, para compartir momentos con familiares y amigos, para ponernos a prueba frente a otros, para aprender con la tecnología o para relajarnos y pasar buenos ratos. Al igual que otras actividades sociales, jugar implica crear relaciones significativas con muchos jugadores y la alegría de jugar nos recuerda que tenemos muchas cosas en común.
        </b></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box__footer">
    <h2>Honey Store</h2>
        <a href="../index.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-house movs"></i><b>Inicio</b></a>
        <a href="../page/nintendo.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-gamepad movs"></i><b>Nintendo</b></a>
        <a href="../page/playstation.html"><i class="fa-brands fa-playstation movs"></i><b>Playstation</b></a>
        <a href="../page/xbox.html"><i class="fa-brands fa-xbox movs"></i><b>Xbox</b></a>
        <a href="../page/contactenos.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-retro movs"></i><b>Contactenos</b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box__footer">
      <h2>Seguinos en nuestras redes</h2>
          <a href=https://www.facebook.com/AyrtonAlexanderRupp/><i class="fab fa-facebook movs" ></i><b>Facebook</b></a>
          <a href=https://twitter.com/ayrton_rupp/><i class="fab fa-twitter movs"></i><b>twitter</b></a>
          <a href=https://www.instagram.com/ayrtonalexanderupp/?hl=es-la/><i class="fab fa-instagram movs"></i><b>instagram</b></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box__copyright">
      <hr>
      <p><b>Todos los derechos reservados a © <b>Honey Store</b> 2022</b></p>
    </div>
    
    </footer>
    
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

`Soy bastante nuevo en esto asi que mis soluciones fueron muy limitadas sencillamente no pude hacer que el json pase bien la informacion para que muestre los productos (el json esta bien no es el problema), la pagina funciona si utilizo un array directamente, mas no si utilizo el json sinceramente tengo pocas mas ideas de como solucionar y espero que alguien pueda verlo y ayudarme por favor

```
iconst API_URL = './productos.json' 

   const handleFetch = () => { 

    fetch(API_URL) // 
    .then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => 
    {
        return data 
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error)) 
}
const productos = handleFetch ()

const contenedorProductos = document.querySelector("#contenedor-productos");
const botonesCategorias = document.querySelectorAll(".boton-categoria");
const tituloPrincipal = document.querySelector("#titulo-principal");
let botonesAgregar = document.querySelectorAll(".producto-agregar");
const numerito = document.querySelector("#numerito");


function cargarProductos(productosElegidos) {

    contenedorProductos.innerHTML = "";

    productosElegidos.forEach(producto => {

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("producto");
        div.innerHTML =  ` 
        <div class="carta card m-5 p-5 border-warning">
        <img src="${producto.imagen}" class="producto-imagen card-img-top" alt="${producto.titulo}">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="producto-titulo card-title">${producto.titulo}</h5>
        <div class="producto-precio card-footer-precio">
            <big class="producto-precio text">$${producto.precio}</big>
          </div>
          <a class="producto-agregar btn btn-dark" id="${producto.id}" role="button">Agregar al carrito</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        `;
        contenedorProductos.append(div);
    })

    actualizarBotonesAgregar();
}

cargarProductos(productos);

botonesCategorias.forEach(boton => {
    boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

        botonesCategorias.forEach(boton => boton.classList.remove("active"));
        e.currentTarget.classList.add("active");

        if (e.currentTarget.id != "todos") {
            const productoCategoria = productos.find(producto => producto.categoria.id === e.currentTarget.id);
            tituloPrincipal.innerText = productoCategoria.categoria.nombre;
            const productosBoton = productos.filter(producto => producto.categoria.id === e.currentTarget.id);
            cargarProductos(productosBoton);
        } else {
            tituloPrincipal.innerText = "Todos los productos";
            cargarProductos(productos);
        }

    })
});

function actualizarBotonesAgregar() {
    botonesAgregar = document.querySelectorAll(".producto-agregar");

    botonesAgregar.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener("click", agregarAlCarrito);
    });
}

let productosEnCarrito;

let productosEnCarritoLS = localStorage.getItem("productos-en-carrito");

if (productosEnCarritoLS) {
    productosEnCarrito = JSON.parse(productosEnCarritoLS);
    actualizarNumerito();
} else {
    productosEnCarrito = [];
}

function agregarAlCarrito(e) {
    const idBoton = e.currentTarget.id;
    const productoAgregado = productos.find(producto => producto.id === idBoton);

    if(productosEnCarrito.some(producto => producto.id === idBoton)) {
        const index = productosEnCarrito.findIndex(producto => producto.id === idBoton);
        productosEnCarrito[index].cantidad++;
    } else {
        productoAgregado.cantidad = 1;
        productosEnCarrito.push(productoAgregado);
    }

    actualizarNumerito();

    localStorage.setItem("productos-en-carrito", JSON.stringify(productosEnCarrito));
}

function actualizarNumerito() {
    let nuevoNumerito = productosEnCarrito.reduce((acc, producto) => acc + producto.cantidad, 0);
    numerito.innerText = nuevoNumerito;
}
```

**[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]ntroducir el código aquí
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bes2s.png**

Comment: agrega el resto de tu codigo amigo, html y css.

Comment: creo que ya esta por lo menos lo mas importante no me dejaba agregar la otra pagina html pero creo que no es necesaria

Comment: el json tambien compañero, la idea es que uno pueda copiar todo a nuestros ide's asi podemos probar el codigo

Comment: al final ya pude solucionarlo, pero muchas gracias

Comment: puedes compartir la respuesta con la comunidad por si alguien tiene el mismo problema